# do solr-4.3.1 can be used for indexed search in hbase-0.94.6.1?

Tags: solr, hbase

I have already setup hadoop-1.1.2 and hbase-0.94.6.1 clusters and it is working perfectly.
Now i have a requirement of using apache solr for implementing search capability on hbase tables data. I choose solr-4.3.1.

I tested the working of solr by configuring solr with mysql as datasource and can able to query for search successfully.

But when i configured solr with hbase as datasource,it gives me error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase- Default . XML file Seems to be for and Old Version of HBase ( null ), this Version is 0.92.1 
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion (HBaseConfiguration.java : 68 )
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)

I googled alot for this error and followed everything as mentioned in hbase configuration documentation and also referred :

http://www.cnblogs.com/panfeng412/archive/2012/07/22/hbase-exception-hbase-default-xml-file-seems-to-be-for-and-old-version-of-HBase.html

but the same error shows up.. Enough source for solving the error also seems to be less.

Can anyone help me in this context?
Thanks in advance..

> ERROR - 2013-07-03 10:05:12.567; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Failed to initialize DataSource: HBase Processing Document # 1
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:266)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Failed to initialize DataSource: HBase Processing Document # 1
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:406)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:319)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:227)
>       ... 3 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Failed to initialize DataSource: HBase Processing Document # 1
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:396)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:99)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.HbaseEntityProcessor.init(HbaseEntityProcessor.java:21)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:74)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:423)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:404)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (null), this version is 0.94.6.1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:68)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:111)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.HbaseDataSource.init(HbaseDataSource.java:57)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:394)
>       ... 10 more

Comment: i am a newbie to solr,i feel little difficult to narrow down to exact solution.can anyone give some example configuration for using solr with hbase as datasource?

Comment: i continue to get same exception,let me post my complete error log her which might be helpful in understanding my exception clearly:

Comment: did you have a look at http://code.google.com/p/hbase-solr-dataimport/ ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you put hbase all lib jar files into solr/lib ?
2. Many references don't have enough data for Solr + HBase information
3. HBase is NoSQL database, maybe it couldn't support JDBC Driver to let DataImportHandler work.